# duplicate image with slightly different name

Tags: jquery, html, image

I need to duplicate the image file and add it after with making a slight change to the file name.

The problem I am having is the var does not change with each image.  This will have to run for many more images so I have to find a way to update the var for each image.

```
<a class="slashc-img-zoom-pan">
<img src="/v/vspfiles/photos/hk01344-1478-1.jpg">
</a>
<a class="slashc-img-zoom-pan">
<img src="/v/vspfiles/photos/sc-00342-1.jpg">
</a>
<a class="slashc-img-zoom-pan">
<img src="/v/vspfiles/photos/bs-0034-534-1.jpg">
</a>

<script>
$('a img').each(function() {
var image_sku = $("a").html().split("-1.jpg")[0];
$(this).after(image_sku + '-2.jpg" >');
});
</script>
```

The outcome is suppose to look like this:

```
<a class="slashc-img-zoom-pan">
<img src="/v/vspfiles/photos/hk01344-1478-1.jpg">
<img src="/v/vspfiles/photos/hk01344-1478-2.jpg">
</a>
<a class="slashc-img-zoom-pan">
<img src="/v/vspfiles/photos/sc-00342-1.jpg">
<img src="/v/vspfiles/photos/sc-00342-2.jpg">
</a>
<a class="slashc-img-zoom-pan">
<img src="/v/vspfiles/photos/bs-0034-534-1.jpg">
<img src="/v/vspfiles/photos/bs-0034-534-2.jpg">
</a>
```

Comment: Are you looking for a one-time tool to do this or something else?

Comment: not quite clear from the question exaclty what you're meaning. Do you need this change to the HTML to happen dynamically when some event happens on the page? Are you looking for javascript code to do this?

Comment: The question has been narrowed down and cleaned up so I thought to ask it in a better manner

Comment: You should edit the original question instead.

Comment: You're still not saying what kind of tool you are looking for, and on what platforms it should run.

Comment: what I am trying to do is have my var image_sku change for each image it adds to instead of being the same exact string each time.  I am just working with a basic html file that will be put onto an asp server.

Comment: Please do not ask the same question over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does it with jQuery.

```
$('a.slashc-img-zoom-pan img:eq(0)').each(function(){
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    var src2 = src.replace('-1.jpg','-2.jpg');
    $('<img src="' + src2 +'" >').appendTo('a.slashc-img-zoom-pan');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/TUzNF/3/

Explanation:

1. get the first instance of the img (necessary, since you will be creating a second)
2. grab the src text
3. replace the end bit
4. add it back to the parent `a`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('a.slashc-img-zoom-pan img').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var image_sku = $this.attr('src').split('-1.jpg')[0];
    $this.after('<img src="' + image_sku + '-2.jpg">');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use whatever programming language you have available to you's loop functionality. For example, in PHP you could do this:

```
<?php
for($i=1;$i<41;$i++) {
    echo '<img src="/v/vspfiles/photos/hk01344-1478-'.$i.'.jpg" />';
}
?>
```

JavaScript (with jQuery):

```
for(i=1;i<41;i++) {
  $('#element').append('<img src="/v/vspfiles/photos/hk01344-1478-' + i + '.jpg" />');
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it with java or jquery?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:
var x = 1;
function CreateImage(){
var img = new Image(1,1); // width, height values are optional params 
img.src = '/v/vspfiles/photos/hk01344-1478-'+x;
x = x+1;
img_id.innerHTML += "<br/>";
img_id.innerHTML += img ;
}
```

assign and id to anchor tag,

and then call this function on the event you want to create image

Comment: I need to be able to change the sku for each image.  I have updated my question with much more detail.